# Why does firebase-auth require so many Google Play Services permissions?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-authentication

I am building my first app with firebase-auth.

I have Google Play Services 10.0.84 installed on my device HTC M8 API api level 23.

I initially have permissions disabled for Google Play Services and I allow them as requested.

When I add the firebase-auth dependency and try to create a user I get a

> E/GoogleApiAvailability: Unexpected error code 19

and I receive a notification request to allow Google Play Services access to Calendar, Camera, Contacts, Microphone, Telephone, Body Sensors, SMS, and Storage.

I would like to know why all these permissions are requested.

I've read CommonsWare's post https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html and as he mentions, I am a small brand and don't want to scare away potential users.

In my simple test case activity I'm not trying to *explicitly* compile any google-play-services or other firebase dependencies apart from

> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1

and I understand that play-services-base, play-services-basement, firebase-analytics, firebase-common and firebase-iid are all added.

The only permission I explicitly request is "android.permission.INTERNET" and I understand from my Merged Manifest that the following are also added:

- android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
- com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE

the three of which seem fair enough.

But does **firebase-auth** need all those other permissions from Google Play Services? (SMS, BODY SENSORS, MICROPHONE etc.) If so why? and if not why does Google Play Services ask for them?

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1"


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My top level build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my simple test activity..

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("example@example.ie", "1234567")
                .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });


        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you resolved this?

Comment: Yes, I had trouble running in the emulator, as you suggested, due to my dev env already being in a VM but my code ran in Genymotion without requesting permissions. I then tried on my device again and it didn't request permissions either. I don't know why or what changed on my device, but it's working now and firebase-auth was not the cause. Thanks very much.

Comment: Good thing we cleared that out. Good job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think firebase-auth is to blame for this. If you're statement is true that

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1
```

is the culprit then I would have encountered this when I ran the [Firebase Android codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#5) which uses firebase-auth, but I didn't.

[Using permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html) is Android's way of protecting "user's privacy or the device's normal operation". If your app uses features like Camera, Microphone and Contacts, you will be asked to write those permissions. The permission is asked on run-time or upon installing depending on targetSdkVersion.

> A basic Android app has no permissions associated with it by default,
>   meaning it cannot do anything that would adversely impact the user
>   experience or any data on the device. To make use of protected
>   features of the device, you must include one or more 
>   tags in your app manifest.
>
> If your app lists normal permissions in its manifest (that is,
>   permissions that don't pose much risk to the user's privacy or the
>   device's operation), the system automatically grants those
>   permissions. If your app lists dangerous permissions in its manifest
>   (that is, permissions that could potentially affect the user's privacy
>   or the device's normal operation), the system asks the user to
>   explicitly grant those permissions.

There is more in-depth explanation of permissions in the [Requesting Permissions guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html) which will hopefully shed light on why they are required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and links. I just built the app from the Firebase Android codelab and ran it with no Google Play Services permissions enabled. A dialog pops up saying the app wont work unless I allow Google Play Services access to Calendar, Camera, Contacts, Microphone, Telephone, Body Sensors, SMS, and Storage. Did you have these permissions disabled when you first ran the codelab?

Comment: Nope that's weird..the firebase friendly chat app doesnt ask for that, i have it on my phone

Comment: So if you go to Settings>Apps>Google Play Services>Permissions, you can have all the permissions disabled and successfully run the Friendly Chat App?

Comment: I didnt have to do that as friendly chat says "no permissions required". Try it on emulator for starters